# How to add action button in livewire datatable laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I use the livewire data table in my Laravel 8 project. So when I'm trying to add an action button in Datatable I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Here is my code

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Zone;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\TableComponent;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Column;

class ZoneTable extends TableComponent
{
    public function query(): Builder
    {
        return Zone::query();
    }
    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make('Zone Name', 'zone_name')
                ->searchable()
                ->sortable(),
            Column::make('Action')->format(function($value,$column,$row){
                return view('zone.action')->with('zone',$row);
            }),

        ];
    }
}
```

I used [this](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables) livewire data table. version of that package is : **"rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables": "^0.4.0"**

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you